# mysql 'order by' problem?

Tags: mysql

each one of them has the option to be stick at the first of the category , now the field name of the stick is n_stick it's 1/0 value , and also each new post has a time , now i need to order the news according to which is it stick new or not, and second to it's time , which mean that all the sticky news show at first ordered by the newest time and after them the non-sticky news also ordered by the newest time , ALL of this in same Query , this is the problem .

I tried this but did not work :

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY n_stick,n_time DESC
```

Also did tried this :

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY n_stick DESC,n_time DESC
```

But also no solution , any help buddy's ?

thank you .

Comment: Please post what does your second query return and what do you think it should return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    news
ORDER BY
        n_stick DESC, n_time DESC
```

should work.

Comment: yes it does work now !! it's really strange , i think i did spilling mistake in field name and when i wrote it here made the right one , thank you man .